# How to move sibling Under absolute element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

How can I prevent absolute position from overlapping and set the margin on the next sibling based on the `position + height` of the targeted image? I'm trying to set the margin to 10px between the image and the paragraph under it.

I prefer to use javascript but if there's any other solutions please feel free to share. The code is a bit long, so I added link to [My code Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/L4njL7j4/1/)
as well.

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  positio: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
}

.div-1,
div-2 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.div-6 {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background: #f00;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.div-3 {
  flex-basis: 65%;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#targetIMG {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="div-1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x100" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="div-2">
      <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-3">
      <div class="div-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x100" alt="" id="targetIMG" /></div>
      <div class="div-5">
        <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to calculate the `#targetIMG` image height to set the `margin-top` value to the paragraph like below

```js
var img = document.querySelector("#targetIMG");
var para = document.querySelector(".para");
var imgHeight = img.offsetHeight;
para.style.marginTop = (imgHeight + 10) + "px";
```

```css
.main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
}

.div-1,
div-2 {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.div-6 {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background: #f00;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.div-3 {
  flex-basis: 65%;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#targetIMG {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script></script>
</head>

<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="div-1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x100" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="div-2">
      <p>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-3">
      <div class="div-4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/700x100" alt="" id="targetIMG" /></div>
      <div class="div-5">
        <p class="para">It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added `window.addEventListener("resize", function(event)` to update the margin when screen size change. is there a better way? or this is good @Bhuwan

Comment: @Adam yes `window.addEventListener("resize", function(event)` is the right way to update the margin on resize, but do you really need to update the margin on resize because I think on a real senario user never resize the window...on load margin automatically calculated based on the image size...

Comment: you're right! but worst case: user might open two pages and resized them to fit on one screen, right? in that case the margin will look bigger than it should be.